# WebAPI ensuring all Responses are automatically UTF8 encoded to avoid unwanted Backlash & Quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We all know that by default WebAPI2 tends to add a backslash and quotes to the `HttpResponseMessage` `Content` message.

Using the standard action code:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World");
    }
```

Returns "\"Hello World\"" which displays "Hello World" (with the quotes).

Where if I change the API method and add encoding:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent("Hello World", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
```

and this solves the problem, as the `Content` result becomes Hello World but just for the `Test` method.

Great, but this has solved the problem only for the `Test` method, not for all the other API methods.

Is there a simple and single way to add the UTF8 Encoding for all `Controller` actions at once?

Comment: The first code is using JSON while the second just returns a string that was converted to bytes. If you don't want JSON use `StringContent`.

Comment: Please explain.. I need to return a string. The second one is what I've found online to solve the problem of the first one. My point was that I'm looking for a simple way to set the Encoding to occur automatically... instead of me having to change every single existing api method.

C++ and C# and ObjectiveC clients are seeing the "\"" backslash so I'm looking for a way to remove it at the server level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem understand what an encoding is. Find out because it is important to know. An encoding is a way to turn a string into bytes.

No encoding in the world adds a backslash and quotes. JSON adds them. JSON is a container format like XML is.

Don't use JSON if you don't want JSON. You don't need to specify UTF8 because it is the default. The default *for string content*. Write yourself a helper that created the `HttpResponseMessage` any way you like. That way you can have any complicated logic you like and still construct a response in one line.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the 1st call returns a JSON and unless you Deserialize it as JSON, you will get the backlash. It's that so? Currently I'm using HttpClient and although I set the Default Header MediaType to be application/json, when I read the response using result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result I get the "backlashes". Is the client not automatically deserializing the response as Json by default?

Comment: If I wanted to use JSON on the server, what would be the right way to NOT get those backlashes on the client response?

Comment: You got it. You somehow have to convince the client to deserialize the JSON. I don't know the right API to do that. You can always deserialize manually.

Comment: [This](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) can help understand better